# C# Stored Procedure configurable in web.config

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, stored-procedures, web

I am working on an Health Check SOAP service that will need to call 1 out of multiple stored procedure based on the service this Health Check is ran by. Is it possible to have the name of the stored procedures within the config? And run specific stored procedures based on the service that is making the call?

Comment: Can you give a code example of what you are trying to do?  Having procedure names in the config sounds funny.

Comment: This is just a spike (no code yet), so I am researching the efforts it would take to do such. One of my colleagues believes we should be able to call a sp if it is configured properly but I haven't heard of such before

Comment: My other option is to continue to build Health Checks individually within each application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not go in that way. This is the most uncommon way how to solve this problem. I think you can build different service providers(***One of them is for stored procedures***) for different situation and you can differentiate them by some keys when you call them. There is another way that you can create generic methods to call a procedure by passing the procedure as a parameter or you might build a procedure wrapper class to make all the different calls. But these are just some theoretical ways how to handle this situation. For more details you must provide more info and some code as well.

Comment: Thanks. I am truly considering your option of passing the sproc name to the service. Which leads me to other questions but I will look this option first.

Answer (score 0):

Better to pass a parameter (an enum??) to your method and let the code figure out which sproc to call.  Leaving the sproc name in the web.config file exposes you to all kinds of security concerns, whereas a one-to-one correlation between an enum value and the sproc name, in code, is far more distinct.  Your approach is not something you want as a loose end in your work product.

Comment: Security concerns? how is that possible, apologize in advance I am a Jr Dev

Comment: If anyone who can access your web.config can easily, point your code to a different SQL object at run-time, then you have on your hands a variant of SQL injection.  https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Comment: ok thanks for the knowledge on this. I knew of sql injections for raw sql but I guess it is feasible to work an injection into a sproc as well.